# How to convert Dates stored to millisecond in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I know there are many examples relating this topic, but almost all are relating new dates or ISODATE() inputs and my problem is wuite different.

I have an existing database in mongoDB, and **I'm trying to subtract two dates** or **convert those dates in millisecond and subtract them**. I'm doing this project:

```
{$project:{
    _id:0,
    'CrtDat':1,
    'CloDat':1,
    "CrtMs": { $millisecond: "$CrtDat" },
    "CloMs": { $millisecond: "$CloDat" },
    "TotalTime": {$subtract: ["$CloMs", "$CrtMs"] }
}},
```

My complete document query:

```
db.tickets.aggregate([
{$match:{
    'Nms.Org': 'Org',
    'Nms.Cmp':'Company'
    }},
{$project:{
    _id:0,
    'CrtDat':1,
    'CloDat':1,
    'Nms.Org':1,
    'Nms.Cmp':1,

    }},

    {$group:
    {_id:{
            Org:'$Nms.Org',
            Cmp:'$Nms.Cmp',
            CrtDate:'$CrtDat',
            CloDate:'$CloDat' 
            },
            Total_Closed:{$sum:1}
        },

    },
    { $project : {
        Total_Closed : 1

  }},
```

])

Apparently I would be able to see in TotalTime: CloMS-CrtMS in milliseconds but robomongo retrieving me the following error message:

```
Error("Printing Stack Trace")@:0
()@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:37
([object Array])@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:866
@(shell):90

uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: can't convert from BSON type NULL to Date",
    "code" : 16006,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

Seems that my dates CrtDat and CloDat are NULL but if I do a db.tickets.findOne() (my collection is called tickets) I can see both dates likes this:

```
Key                     Value                             Type
----------------------------------------------------------------
CrtDat                  2015-05-01 03:36:42.000Z          Date
CloDat                  2015-05-07 09:52:35.000Z          Date
```

My output:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "Org" : "Org",
        "Cmp" : "Company",
        "Wkg" : "Wkg",
        "CurEntNme" : "Entity",
        "CurTskId" : 1,
        "DueDate" : ISODate("2014-11-12T16:01:54.000Z"),
        "CrtDate" : ISODate("2014-11-10T22:01:50.000Z"),
        "CloDate" : ISODate("2014-11-19T00:15:49.000Z")
    },
    "Total_Closed" : 1
}
```

Anybody can help me, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error says `NULL` therefore the field you are referencing does not exist. This is likely an embedded field, where you need to define the whole path.

Comment: I tried to group that fields before the project but now the error message is: "exception: can't convert from BSON type EOO to Date".

Comment: Edited now,I hope you will be able to understand my question. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try converting the datetime fields to a timestamp by using the **[`$mod`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mod/)** and **[`$subtract`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/#exp._S_subtract)** operators in your **[`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline.

Suppose your minimum test case is as follows:

```
db.test.insert(
    {
        CrtDat: ISODate("2015-05-01T03:36:42.962Z"),
        CloDat: ISODate("2015-05-07T09:52:35.517Z")
    }
)
```

The following aggregation pipeline will give you the difference in milliseconds between the two datetime fields:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            'CrtDat':1,
            'CloDat':1,
            "TotalTime": { 
                "$subtract": [                     
                    {                
                        "$subtract": [ "$CloDat", new Date(0) ] 
                    },
                    {                
                        "$subtract": [ "$CrtDat", new Date(0) ] 
                    }
                ] 
            },                     
            "TestTotalTime": { 
                "$subtract": [                     
                    {                
                        "$subtract": [
                            { 
                                "$subtract": [ "$CloDat", new Date(0) ] 
                            },
                            { 
                                "$mod": [
                                    { "$subtract": [ "$CloDat", new Date(0) ] },
                                    5 * 60 * 1000
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {                
                        "$subtract": [
                            { 
                                "$subtract": [ "$CrtDat", new Date(0) ] 
                            },
                            { 
                                "$mod": [
                                    { "$subtract": [ "$CrtDat", new Date(0) ] },
                                    5 * 60 * 1000
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ] 
            }
        }
    }    
])
```

**Sample Output**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "CrtDat" : ISODate("2015-05-01T03:36:42.962Z"),
            "CloDat" : ISODate("2015-05-07T09:52:35.517Z"),
            "TotalTime" : 540952555,
            "TestTotalTime" : 540900000
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

For more examples, refer to the manual on the sections **[Subtract Two Dates](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/#subtract-two-dates)** and **[Subtract Milliseconds from a Date](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/#subtract-milliseconds-from-a-date)**.

Comment: Thank you chridam, is the second time you help me :) looks amazing, I think it will work quite well. Thanks!

Comment: @AlbaOrtega No worries, glad to be of help.

Comment: Hi @chridam I was working again on this query in order to applied it to Jaspersoft and in that application I can't use Date(0), however I can use something similar like: new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse("XX/XX/XXXX") so, do you know which is the value by defatult for Date(0)? which date mongodb applied there?

Comment: @AlbaOrtega Unfortunately I am not pretty sure but I guess you could try the epoch date `new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(new java.util.Date(0L))`?

Comment: Nice, I tried and the result is "01/01/1970", thanks again :D